# Add active class to React Accessible Accordion

Tags: reactjs, accordion

I'm new to react. Can anyone please tell how can I add an 'active' class to accordion item.
I am Using [React Accessible Accordion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-accessible-accordion)

Here's my Code,

Import Part

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    Accordion,
    AccordionItem,
    AccordionItemHeading,
    AccordionItemButton,
    AccordionItemPanel,
} from 'react-accessible-accordion';
```

Render part

```
<Accordion>
    <AccordionItem>
        <AccordionItemHeading>
            <AccordionItemButton>
                <h3>Accordion Title 1</h3>
            </AccordionItemButton>
        </AccordionItemHeading>
        <AccordionItemPanel>
            <p>Description 1</p>
        </AccordionItemPanel>
    </AccordionItem>
    <AccordionItem>
        <AccordionItemHeading>
            <AccordionItemButton>
                <h3>Accordion Title 2</h3>
            </AccordionItemButton>
        </AccordionItemHeading>
        <AccordionItemPanel>
            <p>Description 2</p>
        </AccordionItemPanel>
    </AccordionItem>
</Accordion>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AccordionItem classname](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-accessible-accordion#classname--string--optional--default-accordion__item-): Simple as adding a `className` prop.

```
<Accordion>
  <AccordionItem className="active">
    <AccordionItemHeading>
      <AccordionItemButton>
        <h3>Accordion Title 1</h3>
      </AccordionItemButton>
    </AccordionItemHeading>
    <AccordionItemPanel>
      <p>Description 1</p>
    </AccordionItemPanel>
  </AccordionItem>
  <AccordionItem>
    <AccordionItemHeading>
      <AccordionItemButton>
        <h3>Accordion Title 2</h3>
      </AccordionItemButton>
    </AccordionItemHeading>
    <AccordionItemPanel>
      <p>Description 2</p>
    </AccordionItemPanel>
  </AccordionItem>
</Accordion>
```

css

```
.active {
  // active rules
}
```

Statically setting active this way probably isn't quite what you're going for, here's a demo with some toggleable active state.

[image: Edit eager-microservice-xp7is]